# Is enthought.mayavi.mlab broken?

Tags: enthought

I used to be able to do this in EPD, but this does not work in Canopy. Am I missing something? Thanks,

> > > from enthought.mayavi import mlab
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/home-research/jkitchin/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enthought/mayavi/mlab.py", line 3, in 
> > >           from mayavi.mlab import *
> > >       ImportError: No module named mayavi.mlab
> > >
> > > from enthought.mayavi.mlab import *
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/home-research/jkitchin/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enthought/mayavi/mlab.py", line 3, in 
> > >           from mayavi.mlab import *
> > >       ImportError: No module named mayavi.mlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure Mayav is installed. The enthought namespace has been removed some time ago. You probably have ETSProxy installed but not Mayavi. Can you check in the package manager?

Comment: I had to install vtk and mayavi. I probably did that a long time ago in EPD.  What was tricky is the enthought namespace is still in canopy:

/opt/kitchingroup/CANOPY/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enthought/mayavi/

Thanks for the tip.